# I am trying to bundle the project but couldn't get successful result

Tags: bigcommerce

[image]

This is the pixel union theme. I am trying to bundle the project using **"stencil bundle"** but I can't get the successful result. The error is occurring that the following templates are missing but I saw the original theme and found that there is not available the products folder in the original theme.

Please help me.

Comment: What theme are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

You should have all three of these files in your template:

```
components/products/ratings.html
components/products/price.html
components/common/login-for-pricing.html
```

Did you delete them by chance?  They are certainly in Cornerstone.